# "Ratio" and "proportion" confusions

Tags: ratio

> **Ratio:** How much of one thing compared to the other.

But we have got two different types of definitions of **Proportions:**

> 1. How much of one thing is compared to the total.
> 2. Proportion says two ratios are equal.

And sometimes I see people using the words ratio and proportion alternatively.

As I am a basic mathematics learner I am totally confused.

Please help me understand the two concepts.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A proportion is an equation that sets two ratios equal to each other. A ratio is simply a fraction of two quantities. Does that make sense?

Comment: You are overthinking.  a/b=c/d means that a to b has the same ratio as c to d.  The word proportion is synonymous in this context.  Also f/g=h means the ratio of f to g is h.

Comment: @herbsteinberg do you mean that ratio itself becomes a proportion if we take into consideration things on the both side of the equal sign?

Answer (score 2):

1. The **ratio** of any number of quantities is a quantitative
   comparison of their measures.

   In particular, the binary ratio $T:H$ is equivalent to the
   fraction $\displaystyle\frac TH.$
2. On the other hand, **direct
   proportion** *equates ratios of corresponding values*.

   For example, variables $T$ and $H$ being in (direct) proportion means that  as
   they vary, $$\frac {T_i}{H_i}\equiv \frac
   {T_1}{H_1}=\frac {T_2}{H_2}=\frac {T_3}{H_3};$$ in other words, the pairs of corresponding values $(T_i,H_i)$ are in (direct) proportion.
3. Variables $T$ and $H$ being in **inverse proportion** means that  as
   they vary, $$T_iH_i\equiv T_1H_1=T_2H_2=T_3H_3.$$
4. In less technical contexts, a “**proportion**” of a quantity is a proper fraction or percentage smaller than $100\%.$