# What are direction ratios

Tags: vector-spaces

By definition it is said that the numbers which are proportional to the direction cosines are called direction ratios. And what does proportional means.how it works I didn't get that

Comment: ["Ratio" and "proportion" confusion](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4331538/21813) may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(e_{k})_{k=1}^{n}$ denote the standard basis in $n$-dimensional Euclidean space. (For example, in three space we have $e_{1} = (1, 0, 0)$, $e_{2} = (0, 1, 0)$, and $e_{3} = (0, 0, 1)$.)

If $u = (u_{1}, u_{2}, \dots, u_{n})$ is a unit vector, its Cartesian components are its *direction cosines*. The name originates with the property that if $\theta_{k}$ is the small angle between $u$ and the $k$th standard basis vector, then
$$
u_{k} = u \cdot e_{k} = \cos\theta_{k}.
$$

A vector $x$ is *proportional to* $u$ if $x = tu$ for some real scalar $t$, i.e., if $x_{k} = tu_{k}$ for each $k$. In your terminology, *direction ratios* are the components of $x$. In case it's helpful, direction ratios are *homogeneous coordinates* in $(n-1)$-dimensional projective space.